# Converting LocalDateTime Object to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am new to Java and I am working on Java 8.

I am trying to convert LocalDateTime Object to LocalDateTime but not able to find any way without converting it to String. Is there any direct method for converting Object to LocalDateTime when the underlying Object type is LocalDateTime?

Moreover, if there is any way to convert, can it work for underlying String type LocalDateTime Object too?

Below is my current code which is converting the Object to String before converting it to LocalDateTime as LocalDateTime.parse method needs String input.

```
public static LocalDateTime toDateTime(Object dateTimeObject) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeObject.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
    
    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error/exception with a message? If yes, please [edit] your question and include debugging details. Is the `Object` a `String` or a `LocalDateTime` already? For the latter, you could try to cast it, like `LocalDateTime dateTime = (LocalDateTime) dateTimeObject;`. But that appears somehow weird... Why, if you know the argument will be a `LocalDateTime`, do you use `Object` as parameter type?

Comment: What do you mean by `convert LocalDateTime Object to LocalDateTime`? Could you include example of how you are going to use your `toDateTime( )` method (what will be expecting input and what results you are expecting)?

Comment: If the `Object dateTimeObject` is actually a `LocalDateTime`, you could simply cast it: `LocalDateTime dateTime = (LocalDateTime) dateTimeObject`, as deHaar already mentioned. Otherwise, if the object is some instance of an arbitrary class, you cannot without defining the rules of the conversion.

Comment: @deHaar: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. That's the actual problem I was facing. I was getting LocalDateTime in Object, therefore I was thinking why to cast to string when it is already LocalDateTime. My bad that I didn't think LocalDateTime dateTime = (LocalDateTime) dateTimeObject should work in this case. However, after digging out the code I found that in few cases I may get it as String too, hence I need to handle that as well. So I have updated my code to handle String type Object using the code mentioned in the question and the technique mentioned by you for casting directly

Comment: I have edited the question to mention my confusion clearly. Currently it has been closed but it reopens, I will post my updated code as answer to help someone else in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is a `LocalDateTime`, you can cast the object.

```
public static LocalDateTime toDateTime(Object dateTimeObject) {
    if (dateTimeObject instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        return (LocalDateTime) dateTimeObject;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java 8 LocalDateTime API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) there is no method that takes an Object argument and returns a LocalDateTime. But there is one that takes a CharSequence parameter, which is why it works when you convert the object to String, and why it won't work if you just pass the Object parameter. If you don't want to have to do the call to the toString() method, perhaps the parameter of toDateTime(Object o) should be of a different type.